# Ocultar con ng-hide comparando con los valores de un array

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy realizando una validación de un número de pedido con los elementos de un arreglo para sacar una alert si el pedido esta dentro del arreglo, y en caso de que no este ocultar el alert, pero no se como preguntar esto usando el ng-hide

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
     data-backdrop="static" ng-hide = "data.pedido" == {{AlertPedidosTV}} tooltip 
     title="El pedido ya pasó por contingencias anteriormente, por favor validar!" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-selector="">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation" style="color:red" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
</button>
```

[image]

En amarillo se ve el valor que llega en **data.pedido** y sin color lo que llega en el array **AlerPedidos TV**, en este caso lo que necesito es que me muestre el alert por que el número del pedido (en amarillo ) viene en el arreglo, para que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría un método que recorra el arreglo y lo vaya comparando con data.pedido, si hay coincidencia que devuelva un true, después pones ese método en la vista:
 ng-hide = existPedido();